# How I can smooth the border that is left after applying "Difference" with a "Mesh Boolean" node?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I have the following model where I want to carve a shape into the geometry. I'm trying to use a geometry node so far because I need to create many shapes like this but procedurally.

[image]

My problem now is that I don't know how I could make the border where the intersection happens to be smooth. I found this photo where is possible to see the effect I want

[image]

[image]

Comment: Do you mean you're carving many _different_ shapes?  A procedural  ellipse with good topology would be achievable entirely in GN..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's possible to use  Bevel modifier limiting by weight if you store the Intersecting Edges output of the Mesh Boolean node as an edge attribute called "bevel_weight_edge" like this:

[image]

However with the current setup this produces overlapping geometry with any adequate bevel size for the situation as you can see, so you would need to address that. Maybe you don't need such a dense geometry to create this and could smooth everything with Subdivision surface modifier only as the last step:

[image]

This does not produce very smooth forms, because of the "messy" geometry left after Boolean operation, so maybe it should be modelled some other way if a cleaner result is required. You could try making it from very dense geometry and then smoothing everything:

[image]

But that might get quite intense on computing and memory required.

A more complex node setup somehow generating cleaner topology is needed for a really good solution.

Comment: Yes, I think you are right, I will rethink this then